# After updating to ArcGIS Pro 3.2.0 it now does not recognise .grd files

Tags: arcgis-pro

I recently updated ArcGIS Pro to 3.2.0 but now I receive an error when importing my Global MultiResolution Topography (GMRT) .grd files.

I get the following error message.

> Failed to add data, unsupported data type. GMRTv4_1_1_20230913topo.grd
> Failed to open raster dataset [Failed to open raster dataset]
> Failed to open raster dataset [Failed to open raster dataset]

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Wild guess, so might be a red herring, did you install the interoperability extension too?

Comment: Yes, I have the Data Interoperability extension added as well.

Comment: May be if you can share the data see if others can replicate the problem then you can go to ESRI?

Comment: Thanks, I think it may be to do with the file type. I redownloaded some of the data and it  looks like the GMT v3 Compatible NetCDF .grd files are no longer supported. There are other options (Geotiff, ArcASCII and Coards/CF Compliant NetCDF) but will be a pain for GMRT data in old projects... I couldn't find anything online to say that they have stopped supporting the GMT v3 Compatible NetCDF .grd files